# Azure devops Test plan module : Is it possible to assign testers at the step level rather than assigning to whole test case?

Tags: testing

In our org, we have complex test cases requiring members from different teams to complete the test.
As a part of governance, we want to assign test "steps" (and not the whole test case) to individuals so that we can know how many steps are assigned to each team.

Is it possible?

Couldn't find a way to assign users at test step level